# Possible ways of enabling SSO in Active Directory / Azure Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, entra-id, single-sign-on

I saw in some videos that the recommendation today is to avoid using ADFS for SSO. I would like to confirm that statement and to know what are all the possible ways to enable SSO without using ADFS in an hybrid environment containing Active Directory and Azure Active Directory.
I heard about enabling SSO by GPO and by using Seamless authentication can you give me more insights on this ?

Comment: You're asking for a product. Product requests are off-topic on this forum. This forum is for products that you have, or specific technical questions about a specific product.

Comment: Additionally, Federation isn't going anywhere, regardless of the product used.

Comment: **I saw in some videos that the recommendation today is to avoid using ADFS for SSO** - Anybody can say anything. That doesn't make it right, correct, or true. Maybe you can cite those videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't make it clear what you are intending to SSO *to*, thus some of the comments you've received already. Reading between the lines, I'm guessing you mean enabling SSO for AD users to auth with Azure AD/O365.

If that's the case, the [hybrid auth options are outlined here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/whatis-hybrid-identity): password hash sync (PHS), passthrough authentication (PTA), and ADFS.

These days, unless you have a specific requirement for it (complex federation needs to non-AAD/O365 services), I'd agree that ADFS is often not required in many environments. It also means a lot less infrastructure to deploy. So if you're not likely to need complex external auth setups, you can probably do without. You can also deploy it at a later date if you find you do need it. You can configure OAUTH2 from Azure AD to external services, that covers a lot of scenarios too.

That leaves PHS and PTA. If you want/need password hashes in the cloud, you'd choose the PHS option. I haven't dealt with that requirement myself. I have deployed PTA in the past (I currently work in an ADFS environment), and I found it easy to deploy and manage.

But you need to analyse what's best for your situation. I'd also recommend doing some of the MSFT training courses, if you haven't already, like this one on [hybrid identity](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/hybrid-identity/).

Answer (score 1):

The Azure AD enterprise application allow you to SSO using Azure AD.

See here for an example of an SSO setup with Slack:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/slack-tutorial